# Аналог Comparator.thenComparing из Java в C++

Tags: java, c++, сортировка

Вот немного абстрактный пример сортировки списка в `Java`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь идёт сортировка элементов сначала по хеш-коду, затем по их строковому представлению, затем по тому, являются ли элементы `null`.
То есть элементы разделяются на группы по хеш-коду, в каждой группе они сортируются по строкам и т.д.

Например, если мне нужно отсортировать список строк по длине по возрастанию, а затем в каждой группе передвинуть слова, у которых первая буква "b", вперёд, то результат будет выглядеть так:
`"ara", "bra", "qwerty", "bwerty", "t", "b"` -> `"b", "t", "bra", "ara", "bwerty", "qwerty"`.

Есть ли аналог такого в `C++`?

Comment: Приведите код как текст, а не картинку

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ой, что-то я напортачил. Давно на сайт не заходил, забыл, как здесь всё делается)

Answer (score 0):

В `stl` есть алгоритмы сортировки (функция `sort` и др.), а специально для `list` есть метод `sort`, использование которого похоже на то, что вы приводите в вопросе. Однако есть несколько замечаний:

1. В c++ вы не можете хранить объекты разных типов в контейнерах. В подобных случаях это всегда будет контейнер указателей
2. Метод `sort` возвращает `void`, а не ссылка на контейнер. Это означает что вы не можете поставить оператор `.` сразу после вызова метода сортировки и снова его вызвать уже с другими параметрами. Вам нужно будет сделать это уже в другой строке. Хотя, конечно, вы можете создать объект аналогичный приведенному в вопросе компаратору, в котором просто инкапсулируете соответствующие вызовы

Вот пример:

```cpp
  StringList list{"foxtrot", "charlie", "delta", "alpha", "bravo", "echo"};

  // sort by string size (from lesser to greather)
  auto compare1 = [](const std::string &first, const std::string &second) {
    return first.size() < second.size();
  };
  // put all words started from `b` to front of list
  auto compare2 = [](const std::string &                 first,
                     [[maybe_unused]] const std::string &second) {
    return first[0] == 'b';
  };
  list.sort(compare1);
  list.sort(compare2);

  for (const std::string &str : list) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }
```

Вывод:

```
bravo
echo
delta
alpha
foxtrot
charlie
```

Comment: Можете привести пример, как отсортировать, например, список по двум признакам?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия прямо сейчас не могу - с мобильного писать не удобно.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия дополнил примером

Comment: Вы неверно поняли, что делает код на ява. Я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Кстати, ваш код почему-то вызывает ошибку, если хотя бы два слова начинаются на "b".

Comment: @ИмяФамилия какую ошибку можете привести?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия подобной сортировки по группам в стандартной библиотеке вы не найдете. Можете реализовать сами или поискать решения на гитхабе

Comment: Я понял, как сделать эту сортировку. Там всё довольно просто. Проверяем первое условие, если оно возвращает 0, то проверяем второе и т.д.